# How to set environment variables in apache when using virtual hosting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I am using a virtual hosting to host my php site on apache. For example I want to set http://www.example.com/content/ only this specific directory force to response HTTP/1.0 because I have a application need the content-length in the response header. I've tried to add a .htaccess file in the "content" directory but it seems not work. There are just two lines in the file:

```
SetEnv downgrade-1.0 1
SetEnv force-response-1.0 1
```

Moreover, is there any method to check the variable have changed? I've used phpinfo() to check but it said that still using HTTP/1.1. What's wrong with my .htaccess file?

Expected result is whatever HTTP/1.0 or 1.1 request sent to server, the server will force to response HTTP/1.0 with the Content-Length in the HTTP header.

Thank you.

Comment: [Is `AllowOverride` enabled for this location?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles)

Comment: @Gordon I've tried to add `Deny From All` in the .htaccess, it works, all files in that directory return Error 403 Forbidden. It should be enabled.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I used `phpinfo` in that directory it said `SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1`. Moreoever, I've checked the http header response from server, the `Content-Length` is still missing, it still using chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue.  However, maybe 1 in 20 or 30 of my (all identical) requests will return a response with a content-length header and not chunked.

Answer (score 2):

These directives do work together in your `/content/.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv downgrade-1.0 1
SetEnv force-response-1.0 1
```

This forces an HTTP/1.0 response to clients making an HTTP/1.0 request. Some HTTP/1.0 clients may not behave correctly when given an HTTP/1.1 response, and this can be used to interoperate with them.

[Reference](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-variable-fun-in-htaccess.html)

**To test use command line curl to verify headers instead of `phpinfo()`:**

```
curl -kI -A "Chrome" -L 'localhost/content/'
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 14:52:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) PHP/5.3.29 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1j
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```